# Система сеток для верстки GUI на XAML

Tags: wpf, вёрстка, xaml, gui, дизайн

Т.к. я не в теме то возможно вопрос покажется глупым, просьба не смеяться. Дело в том, что я пишу программу на WPF и недавно на работе возникло непонимание между мной и дизайнером по вопросу — какую сетку нужно использовать при разработке макета пользовательского интерфейса приложения? Раньше он делал дизайн в Adobe Photoshop и только для сайтов на Bootstrap. Использовал 12-ти колоночную PSD сетку. А какие есть параметры для сетки в WPF приложении ? Есть ли какие то стандарты ?

Comment: Никаких стандартов для WPF нету. WPF — это технология, она может отобразить любой дизайн. Привязывайтесь к чему хотите (или к чему ваш дизайнер хочет).

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никаких стандартов для WPF нету. WPF — это технология, она может отобразить любой дизайн. Привязывайтесь к чему хотите (или к чему ваш дизайнер хочет).

Обратной стороной того, что WPF не имеет никакого предпочитаемого стандарта вёрстки, является то, что в нём нет заготовок, которые бы облегчили построение нужного вам дизайна. Поэтому вам придётся кодировать эту вёрстку самостоятельно.

Впрочем, с мощным layout manager'ом WPF это не должно представлять особой сложности.